# Out of range issue within a loop

Tags: python

I try to make a script allowing to loop through a list (*tmpList = openFiles(cop_node)*). This list contains  5 other sublists of 206 components.
The last 200 components of the sublists are string numbers ( a line of 200 string numbers for each component separated with a space character).

I need to loop through the main list and create a new list of 5 components, each new component containing the 200*200 values in float.

My actual code is try to add a second loop to an older code working with the equivalent of one sublist. But python return an error *"Index out of range"*

```
def valuesFiles(cop_node):
tmpList = openFiles(cop_node)
valueList = []
valueListStr = []*len(tmpList)
for j in range (len(tmpList)):
    tmpList = openFiles(cop_node)[j][6:]
    tmpList.reverse()
    for i in range (len(tmpList)):
        splitList = tmpList[i].split(' ')
        valueListStr[j].extend(splitList)
        #valueList.append(float(valueListStr[j][i]))
return(valueList)
```

Comment: I think you should supply an example of input and expected output :) You post is totally unreadable ;)

Comment: well ... it s part of a bigger script so ... i ll do my best

Answer (score 2):

`valueListStr = []*len(tmpList)` does not do what you think it does, if you want a list of lists use a *list comp* with range:

```
valueListStr = [[] for _ in range(len(tmpList))]
```

That will create a list of lists:

```
In [9]: valueListStr = [] * i

In [10]: valueListStr
Out[10]: []

In [11]: valueListStr = [[] for _ in range(i)]

In [12]: valueListStr
Out[12]: [[], [], [], []]
```

So why you get an error is because of `valueListStr[j].extend(splitList)`, you cannot index an empty list.

You don't actually seem to return the list anywhere so I presume you actually want to actually return it, you can also just create lists inside the loop as needed, you can also just loop over `tmpList` and `openFiles(cop_node)`:

```
def valuesFiles(cop_node):
    valueListStr = []
    for j in openFiles(cop_node):
        tmpList = j[6:]
        tmpList.reverse()
        tmp = []
        for s in tmpList:
            tmp.extend(s.split(' '))
        valueListStr.append(tmp)
    return valueListStr
```

Which using `itertools.chain` can become:

```
from itertools import chain
def values_files(cop_node):
    return  [list(chain(*(s.split(' ') for s in  reversed(sub[6:])))) 
             for  sub in openFiles(cop_node)]
```

Comment: @VincentA,  the code is now doing what your code was attempting to do,  I have no idea what `openFiles` returns, from your code it has to be a list of lists, only you can figure out if something is wrong.

Comment: i am dealing with files like this :
http://vbkstudio.com/tmp/LITTO3D_FRA_0895_6238_MNT5_LAMB93_RGF93_IGN69.asc

the last 200 lines contain 200 string numbers.
It is a part of a 20 files database. I m making my test  with 5 files 
For now I can read my 5 .asc files and record the extracted values in a list of 200000 float components but it's to ugly to deal with. That's why I would like to isolate each .asc file in a sublist.
The _openFiles(cop_node)_ function allow to recorded each line of files but i have 6 line of header and 200 lines of strings I need to convert in 200*200 floats

Comment: sorry 1:30 am here ... to exhausted ... I ll study that after i take some rest. @ Padraic Cunningham Thanks for your fast answer

Comment: @VincentA, no worries, the code should based on following the outline of your function should work

Answer (score 0):

```
def valuesFiles(cop_node):
valueListStr = []
for j in openFiles(cop_node):
    tmpList = j[6:]
    tmpList.reverse()
    tmp = []
    for s in tmpList:
        tmp.extend(s.split(' '))
    valueListStr.append(tmp)
return valueListStr
```

After little modification I get it to work as excepted :

```
def valuesFiles(cop_node):
valueList = []
for j in range (len(openFiles(cop_node))):
    tmpList = openFiles(cop_node)[j][6:]
    tmpList.reverse()
    tmpStr =[]
    for s in tmpList:
        tmpStr.extend(s.split(' '))
    tmp = []
    for t in tmpStr:
        tmp.append(float(t))
    valueList.append(tmp)
return(valueList)
```

I don't understand why but the first loop statement didn't work. At the end the I had empty lists like so : [[],[],[],[],[]] . That's why I changed the beginning. Finally I converted the strings to floats.